# Copy video from Resource to UIPasteboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, keyboard, uipasteboard

I am Developing a custom keyboard with Keyboard Extension.

I want to copy video from my resource folder to UIPasteboard. For that i am using below code but no luck

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *moviePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"SampleVideo_1280x720_1mb" ofType:@"mp4"];
NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:movieURL];
[[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard]setPersistent:YES];
[[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] setData:data forPasteboardType:(NSString *)kUTTypeVideo];
```

Can you please help me this?

And one more thing is it Possible to do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No i have checked with NSLog its not nil

Comment: @ Maul did u checked by using breakpoint?

Answer (score 0):

The pasteboardType you are using (kUTTypeVideo) is for a type of movie that has no sound. This will not work. If you copied an mp4 file to the pasteboard using that pasteboardType, and then say, pasted it into an iMessage chat field, it'll show that it's an unknown and unplayable format.

Instead, use kUTTypeQuickTimeMovie or kUTTypeMPEG4. This will work.

Also, no need to setPersistent to Yes; this is the general pasteboard which is a system pasteboard that transcends the space-time of any app, and so you don't need to do that. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. It worked for me.

```
    let pb = UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard()
    let url: NSURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("\(tempArray[indexPath.row])", withExtension: "mp4")!
    let data1: NSData = try! NSData(contentsOfURL: url, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedIfSafe)

    let data: NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)!
    print(data)
    pb.persistent = true
    pb.setData(data1, forPasteboardType: "public.mpeg-4")
```

And also if u want to get the URL of the video from the `NSBundle` you need to add the video locally.